# Xamarin Studio (Mac) - Windows Forms Application? (as in Visual Studio)

Tags: macos, winforms, xamarin-studio

Does Xamarin Studio (mac) create Windows Forms Application (new project) as in Visual Studio - where you drag and drop from toolbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Xamarin not have Windows Forms designer. To create desktop applications with Xamarin drag and drop controls, you have to create a desktop application in Gtk #.

Comment: Appreciate that Rocoso - cleared up my confusion (trying to see if can complete a Windows/Visual Studio based Web Design course on a mac - seems like Xamarin Studio is the answer so far ....)